# Xcode Scrollview issue when using storyboards and Push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode5

I am fairly new to xcode and having an issue with a scrollview. The scrollview works fine...however when using storyboards and push combined i have a problem. When first viewing the scrollview it works fine however when you push to a new page then go back to the storyboard with the scrollview it no longer scrolls. Im thinking this has something to do with the didload and maybe i should be using willappear? The code is below. I think i need to change this code somehow so that it reloads the storyboard everytime go back to this storyboard... Has anyone else come across this issue or advise on how to fix?

```
//
//  PrintViewController.m
//
//

#import "PrintViewController.h"

@interface PrintViewController ()

@end

@implementation PrintViewController
@synthesize PrintScroller, rememberContentOffset;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [PrintScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [PrintScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 595)];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.PrintScroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.rememberContentOffset = self.PrintScroller.contentOffset;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.PrintScroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.rememberContentOffset.y);
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: sorry why you want remember the offset? she you come back don't is the same?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.PrintScroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.rememberContentOffset.y);
}
```

This method could be called by the system repeatedly when the user is scrolling. Since you're setting the content offset each time, the view won't move. You should only do this once and then, say, set `self.rememberContentOffset` to `CGPointZero`, and then avoid changing the content offset if the remembered offset is zero. Something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (self.rememberContentOffset.y > 0) {
        self.PrintScroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.rememberContentOffset.y);
        self.rememberContentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK i have pasted in your code so it now reads as above however it still doesn't scroll when returning to the initial view from a push button in the scrollview? Do i need to delete any of my other code in the .m file as you mention only doing it once? Also in my .h file i have `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PrintViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *PrintScroller;
@property (assign) CGPoint rememberContentOffset;

@end` would this be OK?

Comment: Actually your code works perfectly. if you disable auto layout which i guess isn't ideal?

Comment: If you're having trouble with autolayout turned on, you've probably got a constraint you don't want somewhere. Apple has a good doc on debugging auto-layout which I highly recommend reading.